# Permiso de ejecución en Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Buenas estaba tratando de ejecutar mi código en *IntelliJ* y creo que le he quitado el permiso de ejecución a mi clase *main* sin querer y no se como devolvérselo. En la imagen se puede ver como aparece una x al lado de la clase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa [aquí](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-compiler-settings.html) y también [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11055250/5587982). Has excluido la clase de la compilación. Y, deja de estar trasteando, si no sabes lo que haces :)

Comment: agrega el código de la clase principal, para verificar que todo esté bien.